# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] during modules installation by pip

Tags: python, pip, ipython, jupyter-lab

I have been working in jupyter lab notebook for coding in Python. But I have faced with the one issue, when I want to install a particular module via `pip install module_name` or `%pip install module_name` or `%pip install module_name --u`, I always obtain `'FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified'`.

```
# install webdriver-manager and networkx
%pip install webdriver-manager
pip install networkx --u

----------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[63], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('pip', 'install networkx --u')

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2369, in InteractiveShell.run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2367     kwargs['local_ns'] = self.get_local_scope(stack_depth)
   2368 with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2369     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2370 return result

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\packaging.py:75, in PackagingMagics.pip(self, line)
     72 else:
     73     python = shlex.quote(python)
---> 75 self.shell.system(" ".join([python, "-m", "pip", line]))
     77 print("Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.")

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py:647, in ZMQInteractiveShell.system_piped(self, cmd)
    645         if path is not None:
    646             cmd = f"pushd {path} &&{cmd}"
--> 647         self.user_ns["_exit_code"] = system(cmd)
    648 else:
    649     self.user_ns["_exit_code"] = system(self.var_expand(cmd, depth=1))

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\_process_win32.py:124, in system(cmd)
    122 if path is not None:
    123     cmd = '"pushd %s &&"%s' % (path, cmd)
--> 124 return process_handler(cmd, _system_body)

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\_process_common.py:77, in process_handler(cmd, callback, stderr)
     75 if shell and os.name == 'posix' and 'SHELL' in os.environ:
     76     executable = os.environ['SHELL']
---> 77 p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=shell,
     78                      executable=executable,
     79                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
     80                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
     81                      stderr=stderr,
     82                      close_fds=close_fds)
     84 try:
     85     out = callback(p)

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py:969, in Popen.__init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask, pipesize)
    965         if self.text_mode:
    966             self.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(self.stderr,
    967                     encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
--> 969     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    970                         pass_fds, cwd, env,
    971                         startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
    972                         p2cread, p2cwrite,
    973                         c2pread, c2pwrite,
    974                         errread, errwrite,
    975                         restore_signals,
    976                         gid, gids, uid, umask,
    977                         start_new_session)
    978 except:
    979     # Cleanup if the child failed starting.
    980     for f in filter(None, (self.stdin, self.stdout, self.stderr)):

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\subprocess.py:1438, in Popen._execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_gid, unused_gids, unused_uid, unused_umask, unused_start_new_session)
   1436 # Start the process
   1437 try:
-> 1438     hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1439                              # no special security
   1440                              None, None,
   1441                              int(not close_fds),
   1442                              creationflags,
   1443                              env,
   1444                              cwd,
   1445                              startupinfo)
   1446 finally:
   1447     # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe
   1448     # handles that only the child should have open.  You need
   (...)
   1451     # pipe will not close when the child process exits and the
   1452     # ReadFile will hang.
   1453     self._close_pipe_fds(p2cread, p2cwrite,
   1454                          c2pread, c2pwrite,
   1455                          errread, errwrite)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Or:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

the same result.

Therefore, I always install all needed packages for project via Windows Powershell in command line. And surpass your questions I have created and activated beforehand `venv` for particular project. Version of installed Python is 3.10.5, the python scripts folder is not included into `PATH` environment variable. Could you help me to understand and resolve this issue?

I am sure that after getting advice I will speed up my productivity by installing modules directly in projects notebook.

Comment: Which file is it trying to use but not finding? Maybe edit your question and copy-paste the full output containing the error message as well as the command that triggered it.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. I have added code and more details to the question. Thank you for your attention.